# Does dairy (e.g. crème fraîche) spoil faster if using the same spoon in older and newer product?

Tags: dairy

If I'm using up the last of one package of crème fraîche and then starting on a newer package (later "best by" date), I avoid using the same spoon because of a theory that the newer package will get spoilt quicker.

Does anyone know if there is any sense in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Food in general spoils when bacteria, fungus, and other little bugs eat the food, multiply into more, create waste, and then die. I would imagine that the increased population of "bugs" found on a old, used, not washed spoon would cause the decomposition of new creme fraiche to accelerate, but if you wash the spoon, then no-problem.

Comment: I'm with you there. I always change spoon before starting a new product.